# Assigning Values to and Object from 2 arrays - Java

Tags: java, arrays

Been trying to wrap my head around this logic, maybe you guys can point me in the right direction.

I have two String[], the one contains the Question Options, the other whether the option is correct or not.

Example:

```
String question = "Which of the following are fruit";

String[] questionOptions = "Mangos-Apples-Potatoes-Bananas".split("-");

String[] questionOptionsCorrect = "Y-Y-N-Y".split("-");
```

I am passing a List to my webservice, where each answerObject contains an option, and whether it is the correct option.

Example:

```
List< AnswerObjects > optionList = new ArrayList< AnswerObjects >();

answerObject.setAnswerText(Mangos);

answerObject.setAnswerCorrect(Y);

optionList.add(answerObject);
```

So my question is, How would I loop through the arrays and assign the right option and optionCorrect to each object.

Thanks anyone who's willing to help out.

Comment: Perhaps start by thinking about how to create the `AnswerObject` objects, and how to put them in the list. That might lead you to the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two "parallel" arrays, you can loop on the index of one of them, and use the index for both:

```
if (questionOptionsCorrect.length != questionOptions.length) {
    // Throw an exception here: the arrays must have the same length
    // for the code below to work
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != questionOptionsCorrect.length ; i++) {
    AnswerObjects ans = new AnswerObjects();
    ans.setAnswerText(questionOptions[i]);
    ans.setAnswerCorrect(questionOptionsCorrect[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question array and answer array are parllel

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i< questionOptions.length;i++)
    {
        AnswerObject answerObject = new AnswerObject();
         answerObject.setAnswerText(questionOptions[i]);

        answerObject.setAnswerCorrect(questionOptionsCorrect[i]);
    }
```